# Interrupt a flow of data and disconnect devices

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Basically I'm creating an app that comunicates with two devices through bluetooth. At the beginning I do the connection to the first device, then to the second. At this point I start to recover the data from the two devices (a flow of number). When the user click on "Stop", I have to stop this data reading and disconnect the connected devices. How can I proceed according to you to implement this?

*I use the react-native-ble-plx library*

The first problem is about the function "stopConnection (device)"
I should pass the value of the device: `this.model(this.props.device)`.
At the moment I receive the error. 
`Cannot read property 'cancelConnection' of undefined`

The second problem is that the flow of data is continuous, so when I click on the Stop button about 10 second pass before to stop ("to try to stop xD"). Thank you

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.manager = new BleManager();
    this.state = {
      acc: [],
      gyr: [],
      mg: [],
};

scanDx() {
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      if (device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.ModelDevice)) {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        device
          .connect()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("ConnectedDX.");
            console.log(" ");
            this.scanSx();
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.deviceService_Dx(device);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            Alert.alert("Alert.");
            Actions.homepage();
          });
      }
    });
  }
stopConnection (device) {
    device.cancelConnection()
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(console.log("Disconnected."))
    })
  }

  render() {
    device = this.model_dx(this.props.deviceModel)
    const pressure = this.state.values.hasOwnProperty(this.Pressure)
      ? this.state.values[this.Pressure].join(" ")
      : "-";
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>First Device </Text>
          <Text>{"Time:" + this.state.time}</Text>
          <Text>{"Acc:" + this.state.acc.join(" ")}</Text>
          <Text>{"Gyr:" + this.state.gyr.join(" ")}</Text>
          <Text>{"Mg:" + this.state.mg.join(" ")}</Text>
          <Text>{"Pressure:" + pressure}</Text>
          <Text>{"Msg:" + this.state.info}</Text>
        <View>
        <Text>Second Device: </Text>
          <Text>{"Time:" + this.state.time}</Text>
          <Text>{"Acc:" + this.state.acc_dx.join(" ")}</Text>
          <Text>{"Gyr:" + this.state.gyr_dx.join(" ")}</Text>
          <Text>{"Mg:" + this.state.mg_dx.join(" ")}</Text>
          <Text>{"Pressure:" + pressure}</Text>
          <Text>{"Msg:" + this.state.info}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() => this.stopConnection(device)} >
            <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in the `react-native-ble-plx`  module that stops scanning.

> cancelDeviceConnection(deviceIdentifier: DeviceId): Promise

**Usage**

```js
const manager = new BleManager();
manager.cancelDeviceConnection(DeviceId)
```

OR

If you have a device created through `'new Divice()'`

> new Device(nativeDevice: NativeDevice, manager: BleManager)

---

> cancelConnection(): Promise

```js
stopConnection (device) {
    device.cancelConnection()
        .then((device) => {
       // Do work on device with services and characteristics
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle errors
    });
  }
...
<TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() => this.stopConnection(device)} >
            <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> </View>
```

Comment: @Jack23 If my answer was helpful, would you please include the 'V' sign?

Comment: There is a problem I receive the error: "device.cancelConnection is not a function".
And also I can't decrease the delay by about 10 seconds from when the action is performed at the button

Comment: Do you have a device creator? If not, create a constructor or use a manager.

Comment: I edit my first code with your advices! I use a constructor, but don't undestand what do you refer

Comment: You did not create a device. Instead, a manager has been created. So disconnect using the manager as my answer.

Comment: `onPress={() => this.stopConnection(this.manager)} >`   ===> 
  `this.manager.cancelDeviceConnection().then`

Comment: the "===>" stay for the stopConnection() function? So I don't use a promise but a then and catch?

Comment: Arrowsy is right about you. Use 'then' and 'catch' because the function is a Promise function. This is the use of a motivational function.

Comment: Now the error is: "null" is not a valid Bluetooth Address

Comment: You must enter the device ID as a parameter, as my answer is.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing undefined(out of scope) value to the stopConnection (device) function.

When devices connected

You can keep the reference of device1 and device2 by doing 
`this.device1` and 
`this.device2` or put it in array

while stoping you can use

```
this.device1.cancelConnection()
    .then((device)=>{
        })
    .catch(() => {
        });
```

or

```
stopConnection (device) {
    device.cancelConnection()
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(console.log("Disconnected."))
    })
  }
...
<TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() => this.stopConnection(this.device1)} >
            <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> </View>
```

Example Code:

```
import {BleManager} from 'react-native-ble-plx';

    let connectedDevice = null;
    export default class BlePlx {
        constructor() {
            this.manager = new BleManager();
            this.scanAndConnect()
        }

    onDeviceDisconnected = (device) => {

        connectedDevice = null;

        this.manager && this.manager.destroy();
        this.manager = null;
    };

    disConnectDevice() {

        if (connectedDevice) connectedDevice.cancelConnection().then((device) => this.onDeviceDisconnected(device)).catch(() => {
        });
    }

    scanAndConnect() {

        this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, {scanMode: 2}, (error, device) => {
            if (error) {
                // Handle error (scanning will be stopped automatically)
                return
            }

            // Check if it is a device you are looking for based on advertisement data
            // or other criteria.;

            device.connect()
                .then((device) => {

                    this.device = device;
                    connectedDevice = device;

                    return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()

                })
                .then(this.onConnected)
                .catch((error) => {

                });

            // Stop scanning as it's not necessary if you are scanning for one device.
            //this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
            // Proceed with connection.

        });

    }

    onConnected = (device) => {
// Do work on device with services and characteristics
        this.manager.servicesForDevice(device.id).then(this.getServices);
        this.manager.onDeviceDisconnected(device.id, (error, device) => {
            console.log('DisConnected ' + new Date().toISOString());
            this.onDeviceDisconnected(device)
        })

    };

}
```

Comment: There is a problem I receive the error: "device.cancelConnection is not a function".
And also I can't decrease the delay by about 10 seconds from when the action is performed at the button

Comment: are you using setTimeout() function?

Comment: Nope where I should use it?

Comment: no need of that, but i didn't understand why is the delay. TouchableOpacity takes have some delay of 1-2 seconds for animation. but not more than that.

Comment: can you post onConnection() function?

Comment: The problem is that there is a flow of data (number) from the two devices. (What onConnection() function do you refer? The connection to device?)

Comment: It is nothing to do with flow of data,
 when you are disconnecting device, the value you are passing is null or undefined. if you did not pass any value to the function it takes as undefined.

Comment: And in your opinion why there is so Delay?

Comment: i don't know why is the delay. disconnection will happen immediately